# Ruby on rails simple relationship has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a simple rails app where I am trying to establish the relationship between two models.

I have a plan model and a subscription model.

A subscription will only ever have 1 plan but plans can belong to many subscriptions.

As there is no belong to many relationship I am guessing that the best way to create this is using has_and_belongs_to_many with a join table of plan_subscription - is this correct?

Assuming this is correct how do I ensure that my subscription only ever has a single plan created?

The current code I have is as follows:

```
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
end

class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :subscriptions
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has_and_belongs_to_many association is many to many association and you wrote subscription will only ever have 1 plan, plans can belong to many subscriptions so in this case your association is wrong.Your association will be like this:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plan
end
```

Comment: That makes more sense :) Thanks!

Comment: plus one for the description ;)

Comment: Is it possible to use the following: Plan - has_many subscriptions. Subscription - has_one plan ?